# При инициализации объекта PDO начинается бесконечный запрос

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

В проекте используется 3 БД, с разных серверов. 2 из них работают на одном сервере, 3-я работает на другом, с 3-ей проблемы.

есть вот такой метод инициализирующий объекта PDO

```
public static function getConnection3()
{
    $paramsPath = ROOT.DS.'config'.DS.'db_params3.php';

    $params = include($paramsPath);

    $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']};charset=utf8";

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);


    return $db;

}
```

Параметры подключения к базе проверял , все правильно.
Зависание начинается на строчке с инициализацией объекта PDO

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
```

Пробовал обернуть в try-catch, никаких исключений не выбрасывается, происходит тоже самое.

Доступ на сервере проекта к серверу БД есть.

Какие еще могут быть причины?

Comment: *Зависание начинается на строчке с инициализацией объекта PDO* А получившиеся значения параметров нам предлагается угадать?

Comment: @Akina параметры приходят правильные